# Get RecordID based on ExternalID

Tags: data-loader, externalid, record

I always stumble upon this situation - I have csv file with 200 records and each record has an ExternalId. These records may or may not exist in Salesforce. In Salesforce I have an ExternalID field.

If any of the 200 records exist in  Salesforce I would like to Update those. **UPDATE ONLY, NOT INSERT**.

Data loader requires Salesforce record id for an UPDATE call, it does not UPDATE based on EXTERNALID. It only upserts based on EXTERNALID.

What is the easiest way to get the Salesforce RecordID corresponding to the EXTERNALID ?

Until now I have been running a report of all Accounts in Salesforce [RecordID, ExternalID], exporting these records to csv, then doing a vlookup with the csv that I want to update [ExternalID, FieldTUpdate]. Then creating a new csv with [RecordID, FieldToUpdate]. And finally uploadin this new csv with the UPDATE Call.

I bet there is a better way which I am not aware of.

Comment: Conditional data import is not supported by data loader (AFAIK). Have you checked app store (under the category `IT & Administration` > `Data Cleansing`) for any app that might facilitate this? If nothing is available, you might have to write code to automate all the manual work done over CSV files.

Comment: Realfire (https://www.datasert.com/products/realfire) supports loading data with id lookup and can be configured to error if not lookup not found. Disclaimer: I'm part of team which makes Realfire.